# KeystoneJS docker-compose can't connect mongo db

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, keystonejs

I am trying to deploy keystoneJS app on the server. Before that I want to test it locally.

I started mongoDB locally. Then use the Dockerfile from the documentation https://www.keystonejs.com/guides/deployment here, I can't run it. I get the error below:

```
✖ Connecting to database
Error: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
    at /home/node/node_modules/@keystonejs/utils/dist/utils.cjs.prod.js:54:26
    at async executeDefaultServer (/home/node/node_modules/@keystonejs/keystone/bin/utils.js:109:3) {
  errors: {
    MongooseAdapter: MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
        at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/node/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/server_selection.js:308:9)
        at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
        at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7) {
      name: 'MongoTimeoutError',
      reason: [MongoNetworkError],
      [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
    }
  }
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I googled seems didn't know about local `mongodb://localhost:27017`.

Then I decided to use docker-compose:

Here is the **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: my-admin
    restart: always
    build: .
    volumes:
        - .:/mycode
    environment:
        - MONGO_URI=mongodb://mongo:27017
    ports:
    - "80:3030"
    links:
        - mongo
  mongo:
        image: mongo:latest
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "27017:27017"
```

when I `run docker-compose up`, got the same error.

Also tried this:

```
const keystone = new Keystone({
  name: PROJECT_NAME,
  adapter: new Adapter({mongoUri: "mongodb://mongo:27017/myapp"}),
  onConnect: initialiseData,
});
```

Any help? Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here is the **Dockerfile**

```
# https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/node/
ARG NODE_VERSION=12.10.0
# https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init/releases
ARG DUMB_INIT_VERSION=1.2.2

# Build container
FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}-alpine AS build
ARG DUMB_INIT_VERSION

WORKDIR /home/node

RUN apk add --no-cache build-base python2 yarn && \
    wget -O dumb-init -q https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init/releases/download/v${DUMB_INIT_VERSION}/dumb-init_${DUMB_INIT_VERSION}_amd64 && \
    chmod +x dumb-init
ADD . /home/node
RUN yarn install && yarn build && yarn cache clean

# Runtime container
FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}-alpine

WORKDIR /home/node

COPY --from=build /home/node /home/node

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["./dumb-init", "yarn", "start"]
```

Comment: Is the database actually up when your application starts up?  Waiting longer or using a tool like `wait-for-it` in the client container is a common answer.  Your `links:` are unnecessary and _probably_ don't hurt, but I'd delete that section just to be sure.

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze If I understand correctly, you are saying before I run `docker-compose up` I should start mongo first by `docker run -d -p 27017:27107 -v ~/data:/data/db mongo `?

Comment: No, that configuration is already in your `docker-compose.yml` file.  You have the `app` container marked `restart: always`; if you wait a minute or two, does it eventually start up successfully?

Comment: @DavidMaze nope, keeping get this error. I can see the mongo container is running and I can use local client connect it. Just the keystoneJS can't connect it. Wondering if the `Apdpter` of Keystone issue or `MONGO_URI=mongodb://mongo:27017` isn't correct.

Comment: Just added `Dockerfile`, thanks!

Comment: @DavidMaze Just added `image: my-admin:v1.1`, it works now. thanks for your response!